# Get first matched row for each element in SQL ANY array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    key character(128),
    value character(128),
    timestamp int
);
```

With three rows:

- `key1 -> value1 -> 100`
- `key2 -> value5 -> 200`
- `key1 -> value15 -> 300`

I would like to run a query, where I could get key value pairs for given key. So, for example running

```
SELECT key, value
FROM test
WHERE key = ANY(array['key1', 'key2'])
ORDER by timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1
```

would return

```
key1, value15
key2, value5
```

Right now, the query above returns the most recent element only. How should I modify it to return the most recent element for each item from the 'any' array? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest approach is to unnest the array, and use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (a.key) a.key, t.value
from test t
inner join unnest(array['key1', 'key2']) a(key) on a.key = t.key
order by a.key, t.timestamp desc
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works perfectly.